# Manually installing modules with python3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

My usual workflow for manually installing python modules doesn't work since I upgraded to python3.9 on my mac. Suppose I want to install a custom module called "myfiles" from the setup script, I do

```
cd myfiles
python3 setup.py install --user
```

The output contains the line

```
Extracting myfiles-1.6.1-py3.9.egg to /Users/antonius/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

When I inspect the content of `sys.path`, I see the directory

```
/Users/antonius/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages
```

as well as all other directories under it. However, the directory

```
/Users/antonius/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

does **not** appear in the list of paths. Even if I edit my `~/.zshrc` to include the line

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/antonius/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

then the list of paths contains this directory, but does not contain any of the directories under it, so I cannot import my module.

What is going on? How do I tell python to expand the list of paths from the content of the `site-packages/` directory? Even then, it doesn't seem right that I need to add that path in my `~/.zshrc`.

Btw, the content of my `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file is just

```
[install]
prefix=
```

Comment: Can you install stuff from pip?

Comment: Yes, I can install modules with pip, because pip places the installed modules in `/Users/antonius/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pip`. `pip install --user .` will do the same thing. setup.py is deprecated.